# Send FCM registration immediately the app is installed

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, firebase

I have an app that stores an FCM registration token to a MySQL database. When the app is installed initially the app sends null to the database, but when the app is launched a second time the token is sent to the database.

Is there a way where the token can be sent immediately when the app is installed?

**MainActivity**

```
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){

                        String recent_token = task.getResult().getToken();
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.FCM_PREF), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString(getString(R.string.FCM_TOKEN), recent_token);

                        editor.commit();

                    }else{


                    }
                }
            });
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.FCM_PREF), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String token=sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.FCM_TOKEN),"");
```

Comment: When are you storing the token is when in the `onTokenRefresh` method

Comment: I store the token in shared Preferences, Ive edited the question to include the code I use to generate FCM token

Answer (score 2):

The FCM token is generated asynchronously. Most like you're requesting the token through `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()` when it hasn't been generated yet. To ensure you get the token as soon is it has been generated, [monitor token generation as shown in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#monitor-token-generation):

> ```
> /**
>  * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
>  * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
>  * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
>  */
> @Override
> public void onNewToken(String token) {
>     Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
>
>     // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
>     // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
>     // Instance ID token to your app server.
>     sendRegistrationToServer(token);
> }
> ```

This ensures that you always get called whenever a token gets generated, which happens when the app first runs after installing, and may occur at certain moments after that.

Comment: I should use this code in FirebaseMessagingService or in Main Activity?

Comment: If you look at the sample in the documentation link I provided, it links out to the quickstart app that the code comes from: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/738af0566ebd44752679bb3dca8e4bf21a95ab14/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/java/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L95-L109. So that's in a `FirebaseMessagingService` subclass.